# VSTO Workbook project: Worksheet level ActivateEvent not firing

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

On an existing VSTO Workbook project I need to add another worksheet. I then need to detect when the user has activated said worksheet. So in the Sheet1_StartUp method I add a line

```
ActivateEvent += Sheet1_Activate;
```

And then I create a new method:

```
        void Sheet1_Activate() { 
            MessageBox.Show("Sheet1 activated.");
        }
```

What has been driving me crazy, for 3 days now!, is that it doesn't work.  Also, I have exactly the same construct with other worksheets that were already in the workbook, and it works fine for them.  If I create a new project and do the above, then it DOES work as it should.  So it's something somewhere in the project, but I've run out of ideas as to what it could relate to.  And nowhere in the code do I ever touch the EnableEvents property of the application.
If anybody has seen this behavior before or has any pointers as to where to look, I would very much appreciate it.

Comment: Don't fully understand, but after adding the code as described, rather than testing it by pressing F5, on a whim I tried PUBLISHING it. And lo and behold it then works!  So I'm wondering why that is, and are there any other occasions when code will behave differently when you do  "Debug type" testing?

Comment: Where exactly in the code you subscribe to the `Activate` event?

Comment: Eugene, not sure if this is what you're asking, but the code I listed is in the Sheet1.cs file.  Or (more likely) are you saying that I'm missing some code??  After publishing I went back in to the project and it now works as it should even with "F5" testing.  So the project's state has been changed somehow by virtue of publishing it.  From your question I suspect that what I'm doing CAN work under the right circumstances, but it's not really the right way to do it.